# Cannot read cookie from another page in different web application on same domain Asp.Net

Tags: asp.net, web-applications, cookies

When I open a page from another web application on same domain I am trying to read the cookie that was created on the original page, But it I cant read the cookie. If I move that page in to the same web application then it works, but thats not what I want.

```
[Domain: MyCompany.mobi]
[WebApp A] - create cookie and launch page

Protected Sub Button6_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button6.Click
  Dim aCookie As New HttpCookie("TestCookie")
  aCookie.Value = "Hello World"
  aCookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1)
  Response.Cookies.Add(aCookie)

  Dim script = "window.open('http://MyCompany.mobi/webappB/default.aspx?id=TestCookie')"

  'open page in WebsiteB
  ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Me, Me.GetType, "OpenPage", script, True)
End Sub
```

---

```
[Domain: MyCompany.mobi]
[WebApp B] - read the cookie and display in label

Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    Dim id As String = ""

    If Request.QueryString("id") IsNot Nothing Then id = Request.QueryString("id").ToString

    If Request.Cookies(id) IsNot Nothing Then
        Dim aCookie As HttpCookie = Request.Cookies(id)
        Label1.Text = aCookie.Name & " : " & aCookie.Value
    Else
        Label1.Text = "Cannot read cookie"
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: What does "another website on same domain" mean?

Comment: @SLaks A different application in another virtual folder. Website A is in one virtual folder and Website B is in another. Should be application I will change the question.

Comment: You mean the same **server**. That doesn't make a difference.

Answer (score 0):

Cookies are associated with *domain names*; not the physical servers that are pointed to by DNS.

For security reasons, you cannot read cookies from a different domain name.
You need to pass the information in the URL.

Comment: Sorry for mis-info on question, the apps are in the same domain but different virtual folders in that domain

Comment: What do you see in the Cookies section of the Chrome dev tools? (both in resources and for each request in Network)